# Returning boolean value

Tags: java

My code is this::

```
public Boolean calculation(){

        Double totalQuantitySum = 0d,totalAmountSum=0d;
        Boolean balanced=false;
        for(MaterialAcceptingRejectSheetCustomizationBean bean: materialAcceptingRejectSheetBean.materialAcceptingRejectSheetCustomizationBeanList){

            if(bean.totalAmount != null && bean.totalQuantity!= null){

                totalQuantitySum += bean.totalQuantity;

                totalAmountSum += bean.totalAmount;
                System.out.println(totalQuantitySum+"  "+totalAmountSum);
            }
            if(totalQuantitySum.equals(materialAcceptingRejectSheetBean.totalQty) && totalAmountSum.equals(materialAcceptingRejectSheetBean.totalAmount)){
                balanced= true;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(balanced);
        return balanced;

    }
```

Why this function always return false???

Comment: Because it's never becoming true ?

Comment: how should we know? There are so many unknown factors to us (the array, `totalQuantitySum` ,...)

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `Double` and `Boolean` instead of `double` and `boolean`? Also, `MaterialAcceptingRejectSheetCustomizationBean bean: materialAcceptingRejectSheetBean.materialAcceptingRejectSheetCustomizationBeanList` - Seriously?

Comment: if i put my second 'if block' within first 'if block' with break..then also it retrns false.... hlp plzz

Answer (score 0):

I have only glanced at this but I suspect that the problem might be that you are comparing to a double. You can get errors due to the number of decimal places when dealing with floating point numbers.

Comment: also if the value is set to true the next itteration of the loop could set it to false. try putting a break after balanced= true;